# Questions about instanceTree

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

1. When I use `viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;` it rarely returns `undefined`, is there another way to get it? as a callback maybe?
2. I noticed that `instanceTree.getNodeType(id)` for some models return always 0, as if all nodes are leaf nodes, so I use `instanceTree.getChildCount(id) == 0` instead, is there a chance that `instanceTree.getChildCount()` won't return the correct value too on some models?

Edit: I don't do anything (no logic of mine) before `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is fired.

Comment: can you edit your questions with more details? is there a online link I can test it?

Comment: There's no online example, I can send the models that it happens on them frequently to the support mail and try to make a minimal reproducible example. In the meantime, can you answer 2 please? @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: please send the file then, I believe those problems are interconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you only access the instanceTree **after** the model loads completely.

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function(){
   // access instance tree here.
});
```

Comment: That's what I did, I also find that in some models it happens more often, almost consistently it returns null until on the first try.